# Compute sum_i f(i) x(i) x(i)' fast?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to compute the summation of `f(i) * x(i) * x(i)'`
where `x(i)` is a column vector, `x(i)'` is the transpose, and `f(i)` is a scalar. So it's a weighted sum of outer products.

In MATLAB, this can be achieved pretty fast by using `bsxfun`.
The following code runs in **260 ms** on my laptop (MacBook Air 2010)

```
N = 1e5;
d = 100;
f = randn(N, 1);
x = randn(N, d);
% H = zeros(d, d);

tic;
H = x' * bsxfun(@times, f, x);
toc
```

I've been trying to make Julia do the same job, but I can't get to do it faster.

```
N = int(1e5);
d = 100;
f = randn(N);
x = randn(N, d);

function hess1(x, f)
    N, d = size(x);
    temp = zeros(N, d);
    @simd for kk = 1:N
        @inbounds temp[kk, :] = f[kk] * x[kk, :];
    end
    H = x' * temp;
end

function hess2(x, f)
    N, d = size(x);
    H2 = zeros(d,d);
    @simd for k = 1:N
        @inbounds H2 += f[k] * x[k, :]' * x[k, :];
    end
    return H2
end

function hess3(x, f)
    N, d = size(x);
    H3 = zeros(d,d);
    for k = 1:N
        for k1 = 1:d
            @simd for k2 = 1:d
                @inbounds H3[k1, k2] += x[k, k1] * x[k, k2] * f[k];
            end
        end
    end
    return H3
end
```

The results are

```
@time H1 = hess1(x, f);
@time H2 = hess2(x, f);
@time H3 = hess3(x, f);
elapsed time: 0.776116469 seconds (262480224 bytes allocated, 26.49% gc time)
elapsed time: 30.496472345 seconds (16385442496 bytes allocated, 56.07% gc time)
elapsed time: 2.769934563 seconds (80128 bytes allocated)
```

`hess1` is like MATLAB's `bsxfun` but slower, and `hess3` uses no temporary memory, but significantly slower. My best julia code is 3 times slower than MATLAB.

**How can I make this julia code faster?**

IJulia gist: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/memming/669fb8e78af3338ebf6f

Julia version: 0.3.0-rc1

**EDIT**:
I tested on a more powerful computer (3.5 Ghz Intel i7, 4 core, L2 256kB, L3 8 MB)

- MATLAB R2014a without `-singleCompThread`: **0.053 s**
- MATLAB R2014a *with* `-singleCompThread`: **0.080 s** (@tholy's suggestion)
- Julia 0.3.0-rc1

  - `hess1` elapsed time: **0.215406904** seconds (262498648 bytes allocated, 32.74% gc time)
  - `hess2` elapsed time: 10.722578699 seconds (16384080176 bytes allocated, 62.20% gc time)
  - `hess3` elapsed time: 1.065504355 seconds (80176 bytes allocated)
  - `bsxfunstyle` elapsed time: **0.063540168** seconds (80081072 bytes allocated, 25.04% gc time) (@IainDunning's solution)

Indeed, using `broadcast` is much faster and comparable to MATLAB's bsxfun.

Comment: This question would probably be better asked on Code Review.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Thx for the suggestion, but there doesn't seem to be many Julia users at codereview.

Comment: @IainDunning definitely. Thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `broadcast` function. Here is the [relevant issue discussing the functionality and naming](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/3100).

I implemented your version as well as a `broadcast` version, here is what I found:

```
srand(1988)
N = 100_000
d = 100
f = randn(N, 1)
x = randn(N, d)

function hess1(x, f)
    N, d = size(x);
    temp = zeros(N, d);
    @simd for kk = 1:N
        @inbounds temp[kk, :] = f[kk] * x[kk, :];
    end
    H = x' * temp;
end

function bsxfunstyle(x, f)
    x' * broadcast(*,f,x)
end

# Warmup
hess1(x,f)
bsxfunstyle(x, f)

# For real
println("Hess1")
@time H1 = hess1(x, f)
println("Broadcast")
@time H2 = bsxfunstyle(x, f)

# Check solutions are identical
println(sum(abs(H1-H2)))
```

with output

```
Hess1
elapsed time: 0.324256216 seconds (262498648 bytes allocated, 33.95% gc time)
Broadcast
elapsed time: 0.126647594 seconds (80080696 bytes allocated, 20.22% gc time)
0.0
```

Comment: Yes, I did warm her up! Is there a specific way of doing so? (I just ran the function multiple times before measuring time.)

Comment: Yeah, just run it once before... strange. It is a lot faster on my machine... I'll edit my answer with my full code.

Comment: N = 1e5 right is what original questioner used isn't it?

Comment: Yea, but 1e5 is 100000

Comment: LOL. Yes indeed. Anyway, I've just remembered `bsxfun` is `broadcast` in Julia, so my answer is now completely rewritten.

Comment: I think the `hess1` time difference is completely explainable by processor differences.

Comment: Likewise, have similar results though slightly lower because the processor is slightly faster.  But 2nd version looks better because broadcast avoids getindex/setindex (try `@profile` on both), and probably the *Matlab* implementation also does.

Comment: `bsxfun` is also multithreaded. You could compare `matlab -singleCompThread` if you want to find out what impact that has. You could implement a multithreaded algorithm now using `SharedArray`s, and more pervasive threading is on its way.

Answer (score 2):

There are several performance issues with your functions

- you're creating temporary arrays by `x[kk, :]`.
- you are traversing matrix in rows while they are stored in column order.
- You are using `x'` (which first transpose the matrix) rather than `At_mul_B(x,...)`

A simple modification gives better performances :

```
N = 100_000
d = 100
f = randn(N)
x = randn(N, d)
f = randn(N, 1)
x = randn(N, d)

function hess(x, f)
    N, d = size(x);
    temp = zeros(N, d);
    @inbounds for k1 = 1:d
        @simd for kk = 1:N
           temp[kk, k1] = f[kk] * x[kk, k1]
        end
    end
    H = At_mul_B(x, temp)
end
@time hess(x, f)
# 0.067636 seconds (9 allocations: 76.371 MB, 11.24% gc time)
```